# How to create custom helper to cast object without using CLR supported casting feature?

Tags: c#, vb.net, casting, clr

I just wondering How to create a custom helper to cast specific class object without using CLR support casting feature? for example I have a class with name MyClass

```
MyClass

   property int id
   property string name
   property list Items

End Class
```

I want to convert it like

```
MyClass myclassobj = MyCast(obj)


function MyCast(object obj) as MyClass
    'Some Code here
End function
```

I don't want to use DirectCast and TryCast here.

Comment: You can use extension method on your class for casting then.

Comment: `I don't want to use DirectCast and TryCast here.` <-- what do you mean? may be write another compiler?

Comment: DirectCast and TryCast are basically converts object in all type of class object. But, I want to create a method that can convert any object into my specified class object. I know it can be done directly DirectCast(obj, MyClass) or TryCast(obj, MyClass). But, I don't want to use it.

Comment: @Ehsan Can you describe it more how can I do this? How to use extension method?

Comment: VB.NET supports [conversion operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf7b9sy7.aspx).  You invoke them with CType.  That's not DirectCast or TryCast so should spin your propeller.